# Why isn't it a constexpr in this case?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, constexpr

I have a dumb constexpr version of strlen and the compiler accepts it as constexpr in some cases, but in others it does not, here's an example:

```
template <std::size_t MAX_SIZE>
class FixedString
{
public:
    explicit FixedString(const char* str)
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE; i++)
        {
            data[i] = str[i];
        }
    }

    char data[MAX_SIZE];
};

constexpr std::size_t constexpr_strlen(const char *str)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max(); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] == '\0')
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

// doesn't compile, compiler says non-type template argument is not a constant expression
auto make_string(const char* str)
{
    return FixedString<constexpr_strlen(str)>(str);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr bool IS_DEV = true;

    // works fine
    std::array<int, constexpr_strlen(IS_DEV ? "Development" : "Production")> arr;

    // works fine
    FixedString<constexpr_strlen(IS_DEV ? "Development" : "Production")> str("Develop");

    // doesn't compile, compiler says variable has incomplete type 'void'
    auto string = make_string("Not working");

    return 1;
}
```

Why is it that constexpr_strlen is considered constexpr out of the make_string function and in it's not?

For what I can see here, it can be computed at compile time, can't it?

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work".

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just added more info to the code and by "doesn't work" I mean it doesn't compile, the compiler basically states constexpr_strlen(str) isn't a constexpr when it's inside make_string.

Comment: `i < std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max()` - well, why don't you just leave out the condition then (`for(i = 0;;++i)`)? Alternatively, you could use the internal condition as loop condition (although I think a while loop is nicer then): `size_t i = 0; while(str[i]) { ++i }; return i;`

Comment: Yes, it indeed seems better, but I just wrote that function to test if the "make_string" could be done.

Comment: By the way: Are you going to modify your fixed strings later? If not, it would be much easier just to store the pointer and the length inside. Actually, [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) might already have what you need then...

Comment: The reason why I'm doing this is that we have a very big embedded system running with dynamic STL stuff, like std::string and std::vectors, when most of it could be decided at compile time, I'm trying to port it to fixed size containers, my FixedString is just an example, I wrote it so it would be easier to explain my question here, it's not what I'm actually going to use.

Comment: If it is about string literals - these need to be stored somewhere in code anyway! So I'd have a close look if `std::string_view` is not still a valid alternative, that would safe you quite a lot of trouble.

Comment: I mean: You want to avoid dynamic memory allocation. Sure. You have string constants (do you???). You could just use the the raw pointers then!!! Advantage of `std::string`, though, is that you don't need to iterate over the entire string all the time just to get its length (well, among quite a few others). `std::string_view` comes with the same advantage, but sparing the copy and operating on the raw data (pointer to literal in this case).

Comment: Alright, thanks man, I think I'll use a little bit of both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that `constexpr` functions are by definition intended to be callable at compile-time *as well as* at run-time. Let's start with a simpler example:

```
constexpr int f(int n) { return n };

int n = 7;

// n could be modified!

f(n); // compiler cannot know which value n has at runtime,
      // so the function needs to be executed at runtime as well!

f(7); // well, now right the opposite...
```

So it's quite simple: The result of a `constexpr` function is `constexpr`, too, *if* and only if *all* the arguments the function is called with are `constexpr` themselves (and only then, the function is evaluated at compile-time), otherwise, it will be a runtime value (and the function is evaluated at run-time).

*Inside* `constexpr` functions, though, the compiler cannot know if the function is called with `constexpr` arguments only or not; so function parameters always *need* to be considered non-`constexpr`. And here we are...

(Sure, `make_string` isn't even `constexpr`, but if `constexpr` cannot be assumed for parameters of `constexpr` functions, then even less for normal function parameters...)

Comment: I see... In this case, isn't there a way I can tell the compiler something like "this will only be called with constexpr parameters"?

Comment: Not that I am aware of... You could try something like a template function: `template<size_t N> auto make_string(char const(&array)[N])` and use N inside (subtract 1 for the trailing 0). It would work with string literals, but it wouldn't consider *intermediate* null characters, as (assuming it had worked) your strlen function would have done...

Comment: That's a good approach, but I cannot use it in every situation I need, for example: auto string = make_string(IS_DEV ? "Development" : "Production");, doesn't compile  because the compiler states it's a const char* and it couldn't deduce the templated size. But, I don't understand, the only difference is the ternary operator, which is const btw, why doesn't it work in this case?

Comment: Ternary operator needs to return a common type in both branches - as array length differs, this can only be a pointer. But you cannot pass a pointer as an array (or reference to). You could have an overload of make_string: `template <bool Condition, size_t N, size_t M> auto make_string<char const(&x)[N], char const(&x)[M]) { if constexpr(Condition) return X; return Y; }` and call it via `make_string<IS_DEV>(..., ...);`

Comment: `template <bool Condition, size_t N, size_t M>auto make_string(char const(&str_n)[N], char const(&str_m)[M]){    if constexpr(Condition) return FixedString<N>(str_n);    return FixedString<M>(str_m);}` Doing it like this gives me error C3487: 'FixedString<11>': all return expressions must deduce to the same type: previously it was 'FixedString<12>'.

Comment: Ah, sure, that's right... Of course!!! (I seem to have entered deep sleep phase already - but it's just early afternoon here???) Some might be going to kill me now, but I fear without macros, you won't get where you want to - with exactly that fixed string as you have *now*. We might face a [XY problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), though - see my latest comment to question (-> `std::string_view`)...